# Assigning hidden field value using jquery the correct way

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am using [Toolset](https://toolset.com/) cred forms to create a post. I have a Ajax request which sets the value of hidden field to something. My code

```
jQuery(document).ready( function(){
    jQuery('.download-button').on('click', function(e) {
        var category = jQuery(this).data( 'category' );  
        // Get post type via the 'data-type' attribute of the button.

        e.preventDefault();

        jQuery.ajax({
            url : aj_ajax_demo.ajax_url, // Note that 'aj_ajax_demo' is from the wp_localize_script() call.
            type : 'post',
            data : {
                action : 'edu_check_if_form_filled',  // Note that this is part of the add_action() call.
                nonce : aj_ajax_demo.aj_demo_nonce,  // Note that 'aj_demo_nonce' is from the wp_localize_script() call.
                category : category
            },
            success : function( response ) {

                if(response === category) {
                    $('.js-modal-shopify').toggleClass('is-shown--off-flow').toggleClass('is-hidden--off-flow');
                    $('.wpt-form-hidden').val(response)
                }
                console.log(response);
            },
            error : function( response ) {
                alert('Error retrieving the information: ' + response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This makes my toolset form to not submit. 
The error that is logged is:

```
[15-Nov-2019 10:41:54 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to CRED_Frontend_Form_Flow::form_start() must be an instance of WP_Post, null given, called in
```

This gave me the idea to remove that line `$('.wpt-form-hidden').val(response)` which successfully submits the form. But I need to set the value of hidden field.

This is the response header.

```
Request URL:https://www.xxxxx.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Request Method:POST
Remote Address:11.111.111.11:111
Status Code:
500
Version:HTTP/1.1
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Is there any way I can do that?

Request Payload

```
wpcf-lead-name=bhanubhnau&wpcf-lead-email=bhanu%40krenovate.com&wpcf-lead-number=987654&wpcf-class=1st&category=science&_cred_cred_prefix_post_id=science&_cred_cred_prefix_cred_container_id=science&_cred_cred_prefix_form_id=science&_cred_cred_prefix_form_count=science&form_submit=true&action=cred_submit_form&wpnonce=7ed1509d2a
```

Comment: Sounds like the plugin might be validating the submitted data somehow, and rejects this extra field for some reason. Is this field part of the form created by the plugin itself, or did you add it manually? Is this related to any fields of the custom post type(?) you are trying to edit here, or is it completely unrelated? I guess you might probably have to go this route, https://toolset.com/documentation/user-guides/using-third-party-hidden-fields/

Comment: The hidden field is already added when I created this form (https://imgur.com/rx4TJx6) for the custom post type. Please check I have added my request payload. My category is this request was science. The above code has made the value of all the other parameter as `science` dont know how to avoid it.

Comment: _“The above code has made the value of all the other parameter as `science`”_ - well then you did most likely simply not select the hidden field correctly, so you will need to use a more specific selector for that, than `.wpt-form-hidden`

Comment: I tried using more specific selector `$('input[name=hidden_category]').val(response);` then also I am somehow setting the values of other parameters to my `category` value. This is the link if you want to give it a try : https://www.edumentor.krenovate.xyz/downloads/

Comment: `$('input[name=hidden_category]').length` typed into the browser console results in `1`, so this can’t actually be setting the value of more than one field. And checking the submitted parameters in the AJAX request also clearly shows, that this is sending `hidden_category: science` - that value `science` does not occur anywhere else in the other parameters. So your problem with this must be on the receiving end.

Comment: Yes, it worked. I had something going wrong from the server-side. Thanks, for all the help.